# How to stack two Haldane chains?

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry, topological-phase, spin-chains

This questions is a follow up to a pervious question of mine:

[Inverse of Haldane phase?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/701807/inverse-of-haldane-phase)

Now that I know that Haldane phase is it's own inverse, I am having trouble is visualizing how could we stack two Haldane chains in order to get back the trivial chain. It might not be possible to have a "visual proof" at all. But, by any chance, can we employ the same construction, as used by Max Metlinski for Kitaev chain, in his Lecutre 2 about Anomalies and TQFT ( at 10:45 ).

https://youtu.be/lToc4t_Nxjc?t=646

EDIT1: I will try to imitate the drawings made by Max Metlinski here.
We start with two Kitaev chains. One above, and one below. Two closeby blue circle represent majorana fermions. So the two chains are in "non-trivial" phase since the fermions from two adjacent sites are paired. On each chain, there are two unpaired edge majoranas.

[image: Diagram 1 : Two non-trivial chains stacked on top of each other]

Then he asks to focus on individual boxes, and switch from horizontal links to vertical links. This is what he draws:

[image: Second diagram, horizontal to vertical]

And then he asks to "rotate/flick/tilt" these so that the closest sites are linked now. I am not sure what to draw because I didn't understand this step. However, I know that ultimately, we are supposed to obtain this final configuration ( i.e. two "trivial" Kitaev chains without any edge Majorana ).

[image: Final state]

So, just to reiterate my question:

1. What was the last step that he performed?
2. Why would that step be unidirectional? I mean, we should not be able to combine two trivial chains to get a non-trivial chain, right ? ( We can't add the identity elements of group to get a non-identity element ).

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the construction given in the video?

Comment: Added some diagrams to sketch the construction.

Comment: @baba26 If we don't enforce TRS, then class D has a Z2 classification, so indeed 1+1=0 for the Kitaev chain. (If you want to enforce TRS, then class BDI has a Z classification; in that case you need to stack the Kitaev chain with its spatially inverted partner, i.e. 1+(-1)=0)

Comment: For your original question about stacking two Haldane chains to get the trivial phase: the column on the right of p8 ( https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.05787.pdf )has the answer for you (it comes down to solving a  four-body problem, similar to Metlitski's set-up above---although Metlitski's set-up is even simpler since it comes down to a four-majorana problem, which has dimension d=4; you just need to solve this finite problem and show that the gap remains finite as you interpolate between the different configurations)